# How do I use a controller for a "partial" view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Here is my situation. I have a `layout.blade.php` which most of my pages use. Within this file, I have some partial pieces that I include, like `@include('partials.header')`. I am trying to use a controller to send data to my `header.blade.php` file, but I'm confused as to exactly how this will work since it is included in every view that extends `layout.blade.php`.

What I am trying to do is retrieve a record in my database of any `Game` that has a date of today's date, if it exists, and display the details using blade within the header.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Laravel has something called [slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) for this.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is convenient and I will definitely use it, but I don't understand how I would pull data from my database to use it like this.

Comment: `\App\Game::whereDate('date_field', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->first()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think to define those `Game` as globally shared is way to go.

In your AppServiceProvider boot method

```
public function boot()
{

    view()->composer('partials.header', function ($view) {
        view()->share('todayGames', \App\Game::whereDay('created_at', date('d')->get());
    });

    // or event view()->composer('*', Closure) to share $todayGames accross whole blade
}
```

Render your blade as usual, partial.header blade

```
@foreach ($todayGames as $game)
  // dostuffs
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you! View composers are exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can create a service class method that acts like a controller and use @inject directive to access this in your partial view. This means you do not need to create global variables in boot(), or pass variables into every controller, or pass through the base view layout.blade.php.

```
resources/views/header.blade.php:
@inject('gamesToday', 'App\Services\GamesTodayService')
@foreach ($gamesToday->getTodayGames() as $game)
  // display game details
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's different value you retrieved belong of the game chosen, you can do something like that:

**Controller**

```
$data = Game::select('id', 'name', 'published_date')->first();
return view('game')->with(compact('data'));
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<html><head></head><body>
{{ $date }}
</body></html>
```

**game.blade.php**

```
@extend('layout')
@section('date', $data->date)
@section('content')

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be this

Under your app folder make a class named yourClassNameFacade. Your class would look like this.

```
class yourClassNameFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'keyNameYouDecide';
    }
}
```

Then go to the file app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php and add to the register function

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('keyNameYouDecide', function (){
            //below your logic, in my case a call to the eloquent database model to retrieve all items.
            //but you can return whatever you want and its available in your whole application.
            return \App\MyEloquentClassName::all();
        });
    }
```

Then in your view or any other place you want it in your application you do this to reference it.

view is the following code:

```
{{ resolve('keyNameYouDecide') }}
```

if you want to check what is in it do this:

```
{{ ddd(resolve('keyNameYouDecide')) }}
```

anywhere else in your code you can just do:

```
resolve('keyNameYouDecide'))
```